# Unable to see Container Processes with docker-java

Tags: docker-java

I'm using the docker-java libraries to handle start up of a Docker image:

```
DockerClient dockerClient = DockerClientBuilder.getInstance("unix:///var/run/docker.sock").build(); 
CreateContainerResponse container = dockerClient.createContainerCmd("postgres")
                .withCmd("--bind_ip_all")
                .withHostName("127.0.0.1")
                .withPortBindings(PortBinding.parse("5432:5432")).exec();

dockerClient.startContainerCmd(container.getId()).exec();
```

I can see I'm able to return the containerId from the above command

```
  String containerId = container.getId();
```

However running a '**docker ps**' shows an empty list. Do I miss something in order to start the postgres container image?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I've just relalized that the cause is the

```
 .withCmd("--bind_ip_all")
```

It seems to conflict with my docker configuration. By removing that line I'm able to see the Container with 'docker ps'